# Problems with login in Laravel, variable Auth checks but middleware does not work

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, bootstrap-4

I have a login system, after passing the if, I check Auth :: user () and it has value, but the routes that are in the middleware do not work, what will be the problem?

```php
if (Auth::check() || ($user && Hash::check($password, $user->password))) {
    Auth::login($user);
    return redirect(route('home'));
} else {
    return redirect(route('login'));
}
```

Comment: What "do not work" means to you?

Comment: I don't have access to routes that are protected by Route :: middleware (['auth']) -> group (function ()
     {}

Comment: Of course, `Auth` middleware is supposed to protect this routes for unauthenticated user. Just move the routes that doesn't require an authenticated user outside this group.

Comment: but I want the routes to be protected, what is not working is authentication

Comment: "... what is not working is authentication ... " What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: if I put a "return Auth :: user ();" then Auth :: login ($ user); I get the user which means it worked but I still don't have access to the routes that are protected